# counting combinations and permutations efficiently

Tags: python, algorithm, math, combinations, permutation

I have some code to count permutations and combinations, and I'm trying to make it work better for large numbers.

I've found a better algorithm for permutations that avoids large intermediate results, but I still think I can do better for combinations.

So far, I've put in a special case to reflect the symmetry of nCr, but I'd still like to find a better algorithm that avoids the call to factorial(r), which is an unnecessarily large intermediate result. Without this optimization, the last doctest takes too long trying to calculate factorial(99000).

Can anyone suggest a more efficient way to count combinations?

```
from math import factorial

def product(iterable):
    prod = 1
    for n in iterable:
        prod *= n
    return prod

def npr(n, r):
    """
    Calculate the number of ordered permutations of r items taken from a
    population of size n.

    >>> npr(3, 2)
    6
    >>> npr(100, 20)
    1303995018204712451095685346159820800000
    """
    assert 0 <= r <= n
    return product(range(n - r + 1, n + 1))

def ncr(n, r):
    """
    Calculate the number of unordered combinations of r items taken from a
    population of size n.

    >>> ncr(3, 2)
    3
    >>> ncr(100, 20)
    535983370403809682970
    >>> ncr(100000, 1000) == ncr(100000, 99000)
    True
    """
    assert 0 <= r <= n
    if r > n // 2:
        r = n - r
    return npr(n, r) // factorial(r)
```

Comment: This has been asked a long time ago now, but anyway... I devised an algorithm which calculates C(n, m) = n! / (m! (n-m)!) as long as the result fits into an integer (which could easily be a long integer). I wrote it in Java, but it should be easy to translate it to Python or any other procedural language: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50292530/finding-a-number-of-maximally-different-binary-vectors-from-a-set/50439854#50439854 (look for `combinations(int n, int m)`)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

if n is not far from r then using the recursive definition of combination is probably better, since xC0 == 1 you will only have a few iterations:

The relevant recursive definition here is:

nCr = (n-1)C(r-1) * n/r

This can be nicely computed using tail recursion with the following list:

[(n - r, 0), (n - r + 1, 1), (n - r + 2, 2), ..., (n - 1, r - 1), (n, r)]

which is of course easily generated in Python (we omit the first entry since nC0 = 1) by `izip(xrange(n - r + 1, n+1), xrange(1, r+1))` Note that this assumes r <= n you need to check for that and swap them if they are not. Also to optimize use if r < n/2  then r = n - r.

Now we simply need to apply the recursion step using tail recursion with reduce. We start with 1 since nC0 is 1 and then multiply the current value with the next entry from the list as below.

```
from itertools import izip

reduce(lambda x, y: x * y[0] / y[1], izip(xrange(n - r + 1, n+1), xrange(1, r+1)), 1)
```

Comment: For a single nCr this is better, but when you have multiple nCr's (on the order of N) then the dynamic programming approach is better, even though it has a long setup time, since it won't overflow into a 'bignum' unless necessary.

Answer (score 21):

Two fairly simple suggestions:

1. To avoid overflow, do everything in log space.  Use the fact that log(a * b) = log(a) + log(b), and log(a / b) = log(a) - log(b).  This makes it easy to work with very large factorials:  log(n! / m!) = log(n!) - log(m!), etc.
2. Use the gamma function instead of factorial.  You can find one in `scipy.stats.loggamma`.  It's a much more efficient way to calculate log-factorials than direct summation.  `loggamma(n) == log(factorial(n - 1))`, and similarly, `gamma(n) == factorial(n - 1)`.

Comment: Good suggestion doing things in log space. Not sure what you mean by "for precision" though. Wouldn't using log-floats cause roundoff error for large numbers?

Comment: @Gorgapor:  I guess a clearer way of stating this is:  "To avoid overflow".  Edited.

Comment: Note that this will not give exact results, due to the limited precision of floating-point numbers.

Comment: @starblue:  But you know the real answer has to be an integer, so if you do something like round(exp(logFactorial(n))), it will be exact for small n.  For large n it may be inexact, but anything other than (slow) arbitrary precision would just be dead wrong.

Comment: there is not much trouble in computing this for small n. the point is to compute this accurately for large n, and I'm already using arbitrary precision, because I'm using python longs.

Comment: how do you use the gamma and loggamma functions?  Neither one returns an integer, rather returns a scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen object.

Comment: math.gamma and math.lgamma produce integer results. Still not clear on what the scipy.stats functions are doing.

Answer (score 11):

There's a function for this in scipy which hasn't been mentioned yet: [scipy.special.comb](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.comb.html#scipy.special.comb). It seems efficient based on some quick timing results for your doctest (~0.004 seconds for `comb(100000, 1000, 1) == comb(100000, 99000, 1)`).

[While this specific question seems to be about algorithms the question [is there a math ncr function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941753/is-there-a-math-ncr-function-in-python?lq=1) is marked as a duplicate of this...]

Answer (score 11):

For Python until 3.7:

```py
def prod(items, start=1):
    for item in items:
        start *= item
    return start


def perm(n, k):
    if not 0 <= k <= n:
        raise ValueError(
            'Values must be non-negative and n >= k in perm(n, k)')
    else:
        return prod(range(n - k + 1, n + 1))


def comb(n, k):
    if not 0 <= k <= n:
        raise ValueError(
            'Values must be non-negative and n >= k in comb(n, k)')
    else:
        k = k if k < n - k else n - k
        return prod(range(n - k + 1, n + 1)) // math.factorial(k)
```

---

For Python 3.8+:

- [`math.perm()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.perm)
- [`math.comb()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.comb)

---

Interestingly enough, some manual implementation of the combination function may be faster than `math.comb()`:

```
def math_comb(n, k):
    return math.comb(n, k)


def comb_perm(n, k):
    k = k if k < n - k else n - k
    return math.perm(n, k) // math.factorial(k)


def comb(n, k):
    k = k if k < n - k else n - k
    return prod(range(n - k + 1, n + 1)) // math.factorial(k)


def comb_other(n, k):
    k = k if k > n - k else n - k
    return prod(range(n - k + 1, n + 1)) // math.factorial(k)


def comb_reduce(n, k):
    k = k if k < n - k else n - k
    return functools.reduce(
        lambda x, y: x * y[0] // y[1],
        zip(range(n - k + 1, n + 1), range(1, k + 1)),
        1)


def comb_iter(n, k):
    k = k if k < n - k else n - k
    result = 1
    for i in range(1, k + 1):
        result = result * (n - i + 1) // i
    return result


def comb_iterdiv(n, k):
    k = k if k < n - k else n - k
    result = divider = 1
    for i in range(1, k + 1):
        result *= (n - i + 1)
        divider *= i
    return result // divider


def comb_fact(n, k):
    k = k if k < n - k else n - k
    return math.factorial(n) // math.factorial(n - k) // math.factorial(k)
```

[image: bm]

so that actually `comb_perm()` (implemented with `math.perm()` and `math.factorial()`) is actually faster than `math.comb()` most of the times for these benchamarks, which show the computation time for fixed `n=256` and increasing `k` (up until `k = n // 2`).

Note that `comb_reduce()`, which is quite slow, is essentially the same approach as from [@wich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2096714/5218354), while `comb_iter()`, also relatively slow, is essentially the same approach as [@ZXX's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44600243/5218354).

Partial analysis [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1v4AYjaX_TAaOKDP_yztLksv--WSIMdSF?usp=sharing) (without `comb_math()` and `comb_perm()` since they are not supported in Python's version of Colab -- 3.7 -- as of last edit).

Comment: I beg to differ.  There is no way that a loop with multiplications gets faster as the number of iterations grows - in any universe :-) It would have to have complexity like O(1/ln(n)) => you are faster than theoretical quantum computer :-))))))

Did you check the results? With a big int numeric lib?

Your prod(..) punctures MAX_INT in a jiffy => wraps around. Probably gives a fluctuating curve. The (n-k+1)/k remains int and doesn't lose a bit. When it comes to the puncturing point it flips to float.

Maybe Python's [*] gets faster when you puncture MAX_INT ? :-) because it stops? :-)

Comment: @ZXX perhaps the content of the plots was not sufficiently clear, sorry. Anyway, I am pretty sure I have never written or implied what you are saying. If you refer to `comb_other()` getting faster with larger inputs, that is because of `k` and `n - k` being swapped to show where the expensive computation is happening. You can quite easily check it yourself that all these functions get to the same numerical values, well past the int64 result threshold (and Python has built-in big int support, I think I can safely assume `math.comb()` is giving the correct result).

Comment: Python 3.11 optimized `math.comb`, might be much faster now.

Comment: Good point, I'll add Py3.11 benchmarks when I'll find time for it.

Comment: Would be good to then also include much larger cases in the benchmark. The OP said they have large numbers and they have the doctest `ncr(100000, 1000)`. And even `math.comb(100000, 50000)` takes only like 0.2 seconds now. Btw I don't remember whether `math.comb` was only optimized for large numbers or also for small ones. In any case I suspect it shows better with large numbers.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't need a pure-python solution, [gmpy2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gmpy2) might help (`gmpy2.comb` is very fast).

Comment: thanks for the reference, that's a very good practical solution. this is more of a learning project for me though, and so i'm more interested in the algorithm than the practical result.

Comment: For those who come to this answer some years after it was written, gmpy is now known as gmpy2.

Answer (score 8):

More efficient solution for nCr - space wise and precision wise.

The intermediary (res) is guaranteed to always be int and never larger than the result. Space complexity is O(1) (no lists, no zips, no stack), time complexity is O(r) - exactly r multiplications and r divisions.

```
def ncr(n, r):
    r = min(r, n-r)
    if r == 0: return 1
    res = 1
    for k in range(1,r+1):
        res = res*(n-k+1)/k
    return res
```

Answer (score 6):

```
from scipy import misc
misc.comb(n, k)
```

should allow you to count combinations

Answer (score 5):

If you are computing N choose K (which is what I think you're doing with ncr), there is a dynamic programming solution that may be a lot faster. This will avoid factorial, plus you can keep the table if you want for later use.

Here is a teaching link for it:

http://www.csc.liv.ac.uk/~ped/teachadmin/algor/dyprog.html

I am unsure of how to better solve your first problem, though, sorry.

Edit: Here is the mock-up. There are some pretty hilarious off-by-one errors, so it can certainly stand some more clean up.

```
import sys
n = int(sys.argv[1])+2#100
k = int(sys.argv[2])+1#20
table = [[0]*(n+2)]*(n+2)

for i in range(1,n):
    table[i][i] = 1
for i in range(1,n):
    for j in range(1,n-i):
        x = i+j
        if j == 1: table[x][j] = 1
        else: table[x][j] = table[x-1][j-1] + table[x-1][j]

print table[n][k]
```

Comment: It seems that this implementation is O(n^2) while the tail recursion I laid out is O(n) as far as I can see.

Comment: It seems a different recursive definition is used. here n choose k = n-1 choose k-1 + n-1 choose k, while I used n choose k = n-1 choose k-1 * n/k

Comment: Indeed, such is the case, wich. I will shortly edit this post to include a quick python mock-up of the algorithm. Yours is significantly faster. I will leave my post here, in case if Gorgapor has some exotic machine in which multiplication requires hours. >.>

Comment: This might be O(N^2) but it precalculates all combination pairs of nCr, so if you are gonna use nCr a lot with a lot of different values, this will be faster, because lookups are O(1) and is less susceptable to overflows. For one value the O(N) algo is better though.

Answer (score 4):

If your problem does not require knowing the exact number of permutations or combinations, then you could use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for the factorial.

That would lead to code like this:

```
import math

def stirling(n):
    # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation
    return math.sqrt(2*math.pi*n)*(n/math.e)**n

def npr(n,r):
    return (stirling(n)/stirling(n-r) if n>20 else
            math.factorial(n)/math.factorial(n-r))

def ncr(n,r):    
    return (stirling(n)/stirling(r)/stirling(n-r) if n>20 else
            math.factorial(n)/math.factorial(r)/math.factorial(n-r))

print(npr(3,2))
# 6
print(npr(100,20))
# 1.30426670868e+39
print(ncr(3,2))
# 3
print(ncr(100,20))
# 5.38333246453e+20
```

Comment: the main problem with the factorial is the size of the result, not the time calculating it. also, the values of the result here are much bigger than can be accurately represented by a float value.

Answer (score 1):

Using `xrange()` instead of `range()` will speed things up slightly due to the fact that no intermediate list is created, populated, iterated through, and then destroyed. Also, `reduce()` with `operator.mul`.

Comment: sorry i wasn't clear, my code is python 3, not python 2. range in python 3 is the same as xrange in python 2.

Answer (score 0):

For N choose K you could use Pascals triangle. Basically you would need to keep array of size N around to compute all the N choose K values. Only additions would be required.

Comment: This is basically what Agor suggested, but it would be O(n^2). Since using multiplications and divisions is really not a problem anymore these days, using a different recursion relation one can make the algorithm O(n) as I described.

Answer (score 0):

You could input two integers and import math library to find the factorial and then apply the nCr formula

```
import math
n,r=[int(_)for _ in raw_input().split()]
f=math.factorial
print f(n)/f(r)/f(n-r)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from numpy import prod

def nCr(n,r):
    numerator = range(n, max(n-r,r),-1)
    denominator = range(1, min(n-r,r) +1,1)
    return int(prod(numerator)/prod(denominator))
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. Just import `comb` and `perm` functions from `math` module and get the result!!

Complete code is below:

```
from math import comb, perm
n, r =12, 3
print(comb(n,r), perm(n,r))
```