# Is there a math nCr function in Python?

Tags: python, function, math

Is there a built-in nCr (n choose r) function included in the Python `math` library like the one shown below?

[image: n choose k formula]

I understand that the computation can be programmed, but I thought I'd check to see if it's built-in before I do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096573/counting-combinations-and-permutations-efficiently

Comment: Can [Itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) helps you (http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)

Comment: The duplicate is what I went with... works great.

Comment: You may find [sympy.binomial](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/functions.html#binomial) useful.

Comment: scipy has a function for this: 
`import scipy.misc` then `scipy.misc.comb(N,k)`

Comment: import scipy.misc
scipy.special.comb(10,5)

Comment: If you need to do this in a loop, then you may be better off using pascals triangle.

Comment: @TylerHeers, you'd think so, but nope.  The walrus operator is only available in 3.8, but you can roll this: https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/1139633938572251136 into a loop and get an O(n) calculation of the nth row of Pascal's triangle.

Answer (score 393, accepted):

On Python **3.8**+, use [`math.comb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.comb):

```
>>> from math import comb
>>> comb(10, 3)
120
```

For older versions of Python, you can use the following program:

```
import operator as op
from functools import reduce

def ncr(n, r):
    r = min(r, n-r)
    numer = reduce(op.mul, range(n, n-r, -1), 1)
    denom = reduce(op.mul, range(1, r+1), 1)
    return numer // denom  # or / in Python 2
```

Comment: Why comprehension not just xrange?

Comment: The denominator can be computed using factorial, which is comparable in Python 2 (slightly slower as r increases?) and much faster in Python 3.

Comment: is it better to import operator than to use lambda x,y: x*y ?

Comment: @Netzsooc: op.mul is approximately 25% faster in my quick timing test I did on my computer. YMMV.

Comment: seriously? There is no standard library that does this, like numpy etc?

Comment: @CharlieParker, Installing numpy is not trivial on many environments. Also, why go to such lengths for such a simple problem?

Comment: If you want to handle impossible scenario's (r< 0 or r > n), then and: `if r < 0: return 0` after reseting r to the min.

Comment: I thought this might be handled by the empty `xrange` functions, but then reduce errors out because it does not know the initial value (and even then, the value should be 1 for multiplication, which won't give you the correct answer of 0).

Comment: why min(r, n - r)?

Comment: @frostbite For performance. `ncr(n, r)` is equal to `ncr(n, n-r)`

Comment: Your function does not work perfectly for big numbers. I've used it with `n = 100` and `k = 18` and it returned `3.066451080298821e+19` (also written as `30664510802988208128`) whereas the correct answer is `30664510802988208300`. You can correct this with `numer // denom` instead of `numer / denom`. It will return the result as an integer division instead of a floating point one. I think this behaviour is caused by the lack of precision of a float number.

Comment: @Haltarys  '/' is integer division in python 2, which is the first snippet written in.

Comment: Why did this have to wait till Python 3.8? O.o

Comment: Any idea to do this for permutation? The denum part of this answer is great.

Comment: I would move the python 3.8 answer to the top, since that will be the best solution for most people from now on.

Comment: [`scipy.special.comb`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.comb.html#scipy.special.comb) for older python versions

Answer (score 243):

Do you want iteration? Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).  Common usage:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> itertools.combinations('abcd', 2)
<itertools.combinations object at 0x104e9f010>
>>> list(itertools.combinations('abcd', 2))
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
>>> [''.join(x) for x in itertools.combinations('abcd', 2)]
['ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'bc', 'bd', 'cd']
```

If you just need to compute the formula, [`math.factorial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.factorial) can be used, but is not fast for large combinations, but see `math.comb` below for an optimized calculation available in Python 3.8+:

```py
import math

def ncr(n, r):
    f = math.factorial
    return f(n) // f(r) // f(n-r)

print(ncr(4, 2))  # Output: 6
```

As of Python 3.8, [`math.comb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.comb) can be used and is much faster:

```py
>>> import math
>>> math.comb(4,2)
6
```

Comment: Yeah, but that would be much slower.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025162/statistics-combinations-in-python for better answers, e.g. scipy.comb or gmpy.comb.

Comment: For some definition of "slow".  If computing poker odds it is perfectly acceptable.  The OP didn't specify.

Comment: @Renato: what are you talking about?  This answer isn't dangerous at all.  Do you think that `math.factorial` returns a float, and not an arbitrary-precision integer, maybe?

Comment: On my system it takes 10ms to compute `10000 C 500` and returns an answer of 861 digits.  Accurate and not particularly "slow" :^)

Comment: @RichardFung If we assume that the divisions are integer division (the case in python2, and hopefully the case given that we're doing combinatorics) then that will return 0 for any case with n < r. As a simple proof, factorial is monotonic, therefore if n < r then f(n) < f(r), for any a < b a/b is 0 (for integer division).

Comment: @CrazyCasta You're completely right, I've deleted the comment.

Comment: With Python 3 running this with (6000000, 2). it takes quite a while, not to mention it throws an Overflown error unless you add //. Accepted answer by far faster.

Comment: [`scipy.special.comb`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.comb.html#scipy.special.comb) for older python versions