# Generating all increasing sequences of specific length from an integer interval

Tags: python, function, numpy, sequence

I want to generate all the possible sequences of a specific length from a integer interval. 
(np.arange(start,end))
If it was only sub-multisets of a set of a specific length I could go for:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4941846/257640
Which I am not sure if it would be the most efficient.

So the "subseq" function will be like this:

```
subseq(np.arange(1,4),2)
```

should return:

```
[[1,1],
[1,2],
[1,3],
[2,2],
[2,3],
[3,3]]
```

Thank you.

Comment: I think you're looking for `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`, but I don't know what an integer interval is and I'm not sure why you're concerned about the efficiency.

Comment: @DSM, I will clarify that in edit. Thanks
I am concerned about efficiency because I will deal with large sets with cardinals around 100.
Plus, is this function faithful?

Comment: I think @DSM has answered your question.  `list(combinations_with_replacement(range(1,4), 2))` generates your example output, as a list of tuples.  See if, for example, `combinations_with_replacement(range(1,5), 3)` does what you want.