# How can I generate a list like this with python

Tags: python

Because of unclear description, I reformatted my question as the way @user2346536 told me, thanks @user2346536.

Questions:
I would like to get a list which contains all kinds of possibilities of elements like below:

Given a set of numbers, I want to generate all the 3-Combinations of
them. Also, In such combination any number can be replaced by its
opposite. Hence for `(2,3,4) --> [3,2,4], [2,3,4]` and `[-2,3,4]` are all
valid 'combinations' whereas `[-2,2,4]` or `[3,3,4]` are not.

Has been done perfectly by @Kasra, thanks for kind help.
....Need to learn how to give a question...

Comment: *a list like this* isn't a clear description of what rules govern the creation of that list. How are those numbers produced? All combinatinos of `[2, 3, 4]` and their negatives in any order?

Comment: Yes, sorry to bother you without good enough description!

Comment: as @MartijnPieters said: formally define this list and add the code you've written so far.

Comment: what kind of loops have you tried?  And do you care about the order the sublists appear in?

Comment: thanks to Stack overflow... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941753/is-there-a-math-ncr-function-in-python

I guess you want something like this ? 

    for x in itertools.combinations( [2,-2,3,-3,4,-4],3):
     print (x)

Note: you need to "import itertools" first.

Comment: I wanted to post it as an answer, but the question has been closed.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i do not explain very clearly before. One number and its negative form can not appear at same time. @user2346536

Comment: I guess @Kasra answer is what you need then. Trying to formulate your question: "Given a set of numbers, I want to generate all the 3-Combinations of them. Also, In such combination any number can be replace by its opposite."
Hence for ( 2,3,4 ) --> [3,2,4], [2,3,4] and [-2,3,4] are all valid 'combinations' whereas [-2,2,4] or [3,3,4] are not.

Comment: Here's a one liner: `[list(x) for a in [-2,2] for b in [-3,3] for c in [-4,4] for x in itertools.permutations([a,b,c])]`

Comment: Here's a general solution. `from itertools import permutations;seq = range(2, 5);print sum((list(permutations(v)) for v in ((i if i in u else -i for i in seq) for u in reduce(lambda z, x: z + [y + [x] for y in z], seq, [[]]))), [])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` and `permutations` and `zip` :

```
>>> from itertools import product ,permutations
>>> p=list(permutations(['2','3','4']))
>>> l=[('-'+i,'-'+j,'-'+k) for i,j,k in permutations(['2','3','4'])]
>>> new=zip(l,p)
>>> new
[(('-2', '-3', '-4'), ('2', '3', '4')), (('-2', '-4', '-3'), ('2', '4', '3')), (('-3', '-2', '-4'), ('3', '2', '4')), (('-3', '-4', '-2'), ('3', '4', '2')), (('-4', '-2', '-3'), ('4', '2', '3')), (('-4', '-3', '-2'), ('4', '3', '2'))]
>>> list(list(product(*zip(j,i))) for i,j in new)
[[('2', '3', '4'), ('2', '3', '-4'), ('2', '-3', '4'), ('2', '-3', '-4'), ('-2', '3', '4'), ('-2', '3', '-4'), ('-2', '-3', '4'), ('-2', '-3', '-4')], [('2', '4', '3'), ('2', '4', '-3'), ('2', '-4', '3'), ('2', '-4', '-3'), ('-2', '4', '3'), ('-2', '4', '-3'), ('-2', '-4', '3'), ('-2', '-4', '-3')], [('3', '2', '4'), ('3', '2', '-4'), ('3', '-2', '4'), ('3', '-2', '-4'), ('-3', '2', '4'), ('-3', '2', '-4'), ('-3', '-2', '4'), ('-3', '-2', '-4')], [('3', '4', '2'), ('3', '4', '-2'), ('3', '-4', '2'), ('3', '-4', '-2'), ('-3', '4', '2'), ('-3', '4', '-2'), ('-3', '-4', '2'), ('-3', '-4', '-2')], [('4', '2', '3'), ('4', '2', '-3'), ('4', '-2', '3'), ('4', '-2', '-3'), ('-4', '2', '3'), ('-4', '2', '-3'), ('-4', '-2', '3'), ('-4', '-2', '-3')], [('4', '3', '2'), ('4', '3', '-2'), ('4', '-3', '2'), ('4', '-3', '-2'), ('-4', '3', '2'), ('-4', '3', '-2'), ('-4', '-3', '2'), ('-4', '-3', '-2')]]
```

Demo :

first we must create the permutations of your number list to have all the states :

```
>>> p=list(permutations(['2','3','4']))
[('2', '3', '4'), ('2', '4', '3'), ('3', '2', '4'), ('3', '4', '2'), ('4', '2', '3'), ('4', '3', '2')]
```

then create a permutations like above for negative numbers :

```
>>>[('-'+i,'-'+j,'-'+k) for i,j,k in permutations(['2','3','4'])]
[('-2', '-3', '-4'), ('-2', '-4', '-3'), ('-3', '-2', '-4'), ('-3', '-4', '-2'), ('-4', '-2', '-3'), ('-4', '-3', '-2')]
```

and then `zip` 2 preceding permutations for use them in product statement :

```
>>> new=zip(l,p)
```

Comment: Thanks @Kasra, that is what i want, can learn a lot from your answer.

Comment: a one-liner: `[list(x) for a in [-2,2] for b in [-3,3] for c in [-4,4] for x in itertools.permutations([a,b,c])]`

Comment: @Joel one line with how much cost ??!! with use 4 inner loop ?!

Comment: @Kasra, sorry that, if the list contains 0, there should be some duplicates. So I think you need to modify it to make it strong. Lol!

Comment: @Kasra It's not going to be the fastest (and it is slower than yours), but at least for me, a list comprehension is easier to read

Comment: @Joel if you have zero it became a new problem !