# Combinations are not calculated correctly

Tags: python, recursion, combinations

I found on Wikipedia that C(n,k) = (n-k+1)/k * C(n, k-1).
I did the evidence myself and got that it was correct. Then I implemented it in my function, which is suppose to calculate combinations using recursion without hitting the built-in limit in python. This worked great.. until I put in to great numbers. This is my function:

```
def choose(n, k):
    if not k: 
        return 1
    elif n < k: 
        return 0
    else:
        return int((((n - k + 1) / k)) * choose(n, (k - 1)))
```

It worked if you would use lower numbers such as    choose(1000, 4), but if you try numbers such as choose(1000,800) it will return the first 13 number right, but then get everything wrong. How come this occurs and even more important, how do you solve it?

Comment: Is this relevant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538551/handling-very-large-numbers-in-python

Comment: If your goal is to calculate nCr is this relevent ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941753/is-there-a-math-ncr-function-in-python ?

Comment: This seems like the usual problem with `float`ing point precision.

Answer (score 2):

`(n - k + 1) / k` will often not be an integer, as `k` won't always divide `n-k+1`, though it divides `choose(n, (k - 1)) * (n-k+1)`.

So, in order to always manipulate integers (whose size is unlimited), you must multiply first, **then** divide using **integer** division:

```
def choose(n, k):
    if k == 0: 
        return 1
    elif n < k: 
        return 0
    else:
        return (n - k + 1) * choose(n, (k - 1)) // k
```

Comment: But this will return an error for example choose(1000,999). Any way of fixing it? @Thierry Lathuille

Comment: You've hit the recursion limit, which is 1000 levels by default. Using recursion to calculate numbers of combinations is not a very efficient method anyway, as you can see. Use loops instead.

Comment: My task is to do it with specifically recursion @Thierry Lathuille