# Retain the previous index of the dataframe as a column after setting another column as a index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe(test4) of the following kind with `Yrs` as a index column-

```
                  Prs_90      Prs_80      Prs_70
        Yrs                                     
        2012  499.934588  521.512345  425.189729
        2013  579.063531  477.782099  256.382494
        2014  458.415624  456.480642  363.309507
        2015  422.547029  320.282754  578.728535
```

Now , I want to set `Prs_90` as a index which I am doing using 
`test4.set_index("Prs_90", inplace = True)`

but it is removing the `Yrs` index completely which I want to retain.

```
                       Prs_80      Prs_70
           Prs_90                            
       854.819691  514.883611  338.596315
       780.394013  488.100756  417.143175
       752.188841  326.476833  644.588971
       703.369157  542.508996  361.643381
```

Expected Output-

```
                   Prs_80      Prs_70   Yrs
       Prs_90                            
   854.819691  514.883611  338.596315   2012
   780.394013  488.100756  417.143175   2013
   752.188841  326.476833  644.588971   2014
   703.369157  542.508996  361.643381   2015
```

How to do it?

Comment: Add `append=True`

Comment: but I don't want the previous index as one of the current index

Comment: Okay, you can use `df.assign(Yrs=df.index).set_index('Prs_90')`.

Comment: `test4=test4.reset_index().set_index("Prs_90")` ?

Comment: Why would you want a `float` index? Seems like an XY problem.

Comment: @jpp I need it for further processing of some other problem

Comment: Almost certainly, you're going about "some other problem" incorrectly - but beyond the scope of this question, clearly.

Comment: I want to implement the solution mentioned in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54435024/choose-r-outcomes-from-n-possibilities-efficiently-in-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
test4.reset_index(drop=False).set_index("Prs_90")
```

Answer (score 1):

Before introducing the new Prs_90 index you can call

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

reset_index() will make the present index into a column.