# Probability of k wins out of n, given p?

Tags: python, probability, combinatorics

Given n trials, with a probability p of winning each trial, what is the probability of winning r or more trials?

My thinking goes as follows:
Each combination of wins and losses has probability p^w * (p-1)^(n-w) where w is number of wins.

Each number of wins can occur in nCr combinations, ex. winning 2 out 3 times means you might lose the first, the second or the third times, e.g. three combinations.

So the probability of winning 2 out of 3 times is 3C2 * p^2 * (1-p)^1.
The probability of winning 2 or more times is just the sum of this calculation for 2 and 3 wins.

I have the following code:

```
import math

def nCr(n,r):
    f = math.factorial
    return f(n) / f(r) / f(n-r)

def prob_at_least(n, r, p):
    probs = [nCr(n,k)*pow(p,k)*pow(1.0-p,n-k) for k in range(r, n+1)]
    return sum(probs)
```

This code works, but is there a built-in function, or a shorter way to achieve the same?

Comment: This sounds like pure math question, and should be asked on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, but I am specifically looking for a built-in python function, or shorter python implementation. My question is not about the underlying math.

Comment: Might be a duplicate to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941753/is-there-a-math-ncr-function-in-python

Comment: That question concerns nCr, which I have implemented in the first part of my code, but is only a subordinate part of my code and problem.

Comment: `numpy.random.binomial`?

Comment: What Python version do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `scipy.stats` module, you could use `binom`.

```
>>> import scipy.stats as scs
>>> print(scs.binom.pmf(2, 5, .5))
0.3125
```

Edit: to get r or more:

```
>>> trials = 0
>>> n = 5
>>> r = 2
>>> p = .5
>>> for i in range(r):
    trials += scs.binom.pmf(i, n, p)
 r_or_more = 1 - trials
```

Edit: the solution given by ljeabmreosn gives the cumulative distribution function which doesn't require my loop.

Comment: You can also use `1 - scs.binom.cdf(r-1, n, p)` to calculate the probability of at least `r` wins.

Answer (score 1):

There are [much faster ways to implement combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4941932/7583953):

```
import operator as op
from functools import reduce

def nCr(n, r):
    r = min(r, n-r)
    numerator = reduce(op.mul, range(n, n-r, -1), 1)
    denominator = reduce(op.mul, range(1, r+1), 1)
    return numerator / denominator
```

But if you're doing this a lot, you might want to consider a package like scipy, which has [`special.comb`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.comb.html#scipy.special.comb) for efficient combination calculation

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know if a faster or more standard method exists for my prob_at_least function too?

Comment: I don't think there's a more efficient formula, but doing it on a numpy array will certainly be faster than a python list.

Comment: If my answer helped, would you mind clicking the little check beneath the score, which will mark it "accepted"?

Comment: @AlecAlameddine How come your rep is 1?

Comment: And this answer is a bit wrong - in Python3 `/` is float division, so value returned from `nCr()` would be float. You should use `//` divison here, and in case of Python2 `import division from __future__`