# Galton Code - From Recursive to Iterative

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

```
def galton(m, n):
    if m == 0:
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        if n == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return (galton(m-1, n-1) + galton(m-1, n))
```

Hello,
does anybody know how I can change this Code from recursive to iterative? 
I tried it with the Galton formula, but I only got the probability.

Code:

```
import operator as op
from functools import reduce

def ncr(n, r):
    r = min(r, n-r)
    numer = reduce(op.mul, range(n, n-r, -1), 1)
    denom = reduce(op.mul, range(1, r+1), 1)
    return numer / denom *(0.5**n)
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by getting the probability. Why do you multiply by `(0.5**n)`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `galton` function appears to be just a [recursive implementation of 'nCr'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Recursive_formula) and so [any nCr function works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941753/is-there-a-math-ncr-function-in-python) with a slight alteration to return zero in case `r > n`:

```
def ncr(n, r):
    if r > n:
         return 0
    r = min(r, n-r)
    numer = reduce(op.mul, range(n, n-r, -1), 1)
    denom = reduce(op.mul, range(1, r+1), 1)
    return numer // denom
```