# Generate product of list with conditions

Tags: python, performance, filter, tuples, product

I want processing large numbers with `10k`+ digits, so I use tuples, because integer type cannot be used (precision of number is important, because sum of digits). There are only 2 unique digits, `9` and `0`.

First condition: Modulo of sum of digits with 999 is 0.
Second condition: It is large integer number, so first digit cannot be `0`.
Last condition: Last digit is `0`.

My solution is:

```
from itertools import product

L = [10000,11000,12000]

for M in L:
    for i in product([0, 9], repeat=M):
        if i[0] != 0 and i[-1] == 0:
            s = sum(i)
            if s % 999 == 0:
                print (s)
```

Is possible count number of generated values with these conditions? Is possible change solution/another solution(s) for reduce time of generating expected output, e.g. generate only digits with `sum of digits` is more like `999`? I am thinking about `Decimal`, but here is problem with `sum` of digits. Order of generated `number`s (tuples, arrays) is not important.

It is so huge tuples, so problematic easy testing.I try create some sample (not idea if useful):

```
for i in product([9, 0], repeat=20):
    if i[0] != 0 and i[-1] == 0:
        s = sum(i)
        if s % 99 == 0:
            print (i, s)
```

Comment: Can  you provide an example:  input and the expected output

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb - Input are `[0,9]` and `M` list. But because large numbers od not easy generate I try create last paragrapf for see, what I mean.

Comment: [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388165/how-to-find-the-smallest-number-with-just-0-and-1-which-is-divided-by-a-give)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of such possible numbers would be too large to generate all.

Let's call L the number of digits in your number, and n the number of 9.

Modulo of sum of digits with 999 is 0 means that:
n*9 = m*999, so n = k*111 where k is an integer.

The first digit is 9, and the last is 0, so there are L-2 places left to put the remaining (k*111 - 1) 9 digits.

So, the number of such numbers is the sum of the number of combinations ( (L-2) choose (k*111-1) ) for k between 1 and int((L-1)/111))

So, a possible code:

```
import operator as op
from functools import reduce

# From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941753/is-there-a-math-ncr-function-in-python
def ncr(n, r):
    r = min(r, n-r)
    numer = reduce(op.mul, range(n, n-r, -1), 1)
    denom = reduce(op.mul, range(1, r+1), 1)
    return numer // denom  # Changed for integer division

def possible_numbers(L):
    return sum(ncr(L-2, 111*k - 1) for k in range(1, (L-1)//111))

print(possible_numbers(10000))

# 46506588317635469366401415658013639152242514965252855714041144018498987152707044490194457854465305060020773686383485941436739496916009717012616366376246414571169910310699834725291436347258613064146124967400646078243663290971123135369040450765747850207912640778375391521167004887068454467534692885571315434928724105198818380334746555427574950364615165695566283976630032289652540054620732064526597228268611847676696899672765577347754597526393233231013911103228183531257080334315932738035622562131489280570776426153110319970303630143757955230868260221372217820886676391878309046535523092899792732603384686832015291205699914402933832273424671204699396414708887671531202101527299797220557526495935874078061714541726044022824401127277289199364810083989340886903060879319068042995827037751119856277555325118818012910801413269671414202747818363564693812789991123599795926600974448559896232026533659303781683288750777356519373140416641070335357434342957815577446771837059264519071351111701743419392138893923198793667574531536322827159764885405347516087975885606826893886851504292563461335005149974908491745377479301673268815242719993061641393932755789000155034631404392298259100662543152918803846714114697300923960523557500317195566759812657273510052876469933988067730551693799653175259045326679352888837840615599025061763546193617710870648379633919635058872421276909819607798170545658257733866028814603688331134993133516485082037147925444085128568947517112262094010118995477748614613681297345233932152146172358997240155349554049974584904754905949454881684316277423691704957916937555749917546766207774972493217477043714652995265409684903579726779500656471405514359721102426435531185506178592945522184727847016844486420511644284474508534529688998209007331208512957982383305010070433027822069432758467560863914508655552438978200137331142103777139831138329641584247585016869654053739406398693488384069254725347054264531039092260379613683402826431841651702016107570078218034751759156452991362380781969813524106141836783707976391132433066632109509663706711194120392913346984831497576260954280288258157219236029228818152608039675500130313183928069363862241906263121908112579346403564641214804122206420758371341181045355185272831160085528848859295608701517219671599684543743252593692174235989978345204406049350779297271034684859111097644033128750102959471412294900623227232358717924727059914175333714529865811974930107943791917826273949743788824216294023431731389259674185985763199421896541289618952210976760618905706699064025869740093553019041859274291091877197046340635783795996884883288761816361022414903437664468405527174106098428305866565043923442930029525366818247447766037463650273567442968538251684623455304412633953426243893756890813731429721493555818339963997009857257028373522283512536995315377100044676823672536566066483879259428166867133820082490868856820190168040370122307493700971959637546773031509327007856264111997525714829526125911250334270232166355120078967567596110824407335535205220718583123846127299455

# It's 3008 digits long....
```

Comment: Thank you. So is possible create some loop like  `i for i in iterator` for generate this numbers?

Comment: It would be possible, but for numbers of 10000 digits, there are more than 4*10**3008 such numbers... Do you want some specific ones, with more conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Less mathematical solution would be using dynamic programming:

```
M = 1000
cache = {}

def dp(i, v, sum_of_digits):
  if(i == M-1):
    return sum_of_digits % 999 == 0 and v == 0

  if((i, sum_of_digits) in cache):
    return cache.get((i, sum_of_digits))

  result = dp(i + 1, 0, sum_of_digits) + dp(i + 1, 9, sum_of_digits + 9)
  cache[(i, sum_of_digits)] = result
  return result


print(dp(0, 9, 9))
```

Output:

```
281853033550040537904406694735205583322614867369419355514834998793657889372557150681302072580895266688090267034276630517914503707145674628565136259594047883519869400688956077638702940707076342539608905721192230524534619011898800645140130344499642277977871480846234887754725793524573506157312565257
```

**Explanation**:

Dynamic programming algorithm works by *memoizing* the sub-results it gets. In our case it is the `cache` `dict` who store the sub-results.

At each invocation we have two possibilities: 1) either the next digit is 0; so we do not increase `sum_of_digits`; 2) or it is 9; so we increase the `sum_of_digits`.

At each invocation we memoize the results we get by summing the two sub results: `dp(i + 1, 0, sum_of_digits), dp(i + 1, 9, sum_of_digits + 9)`.

we terminate when there is `M` number of digits, returning `True` if `sum_of_digits` modulo 999 is 0 and last digit `v` is 0.

Note we do not check for the first digit because, we always have 9 as the first digit `dp(0, 9, 9)`.

**Note:**

1. you may need to increase maximum recursion depth using:

   `sys.setrecursionlimit(XXXXXX..)`

   or you can transform the recursive solution to iterative(it is always possible to do that).
2. Although this solution is more efficient than the brute-force solution, @Thierry_Lathuille is more efficient than this solution,.