# Get value from Pyramid by finding a contruction pattern with Python

Tags: python

Can someone help me with this problem.
[image]

Here is my code but it is far away to the solution

```
def get_value_from_pyramid(l):
    for i in range(0,l):
        num=1
        for j in range(0,i+1):
            if i == j:
                num=1
            print(num, end=" ")
            num+=1
        print("\r")
```

Comment: You seem to have just 'tried' some code. I would take a long look at the image of the 'pyramid' and see if you can write a function which implements some of the more simple examples. For instance any of the calls where the `c` parameter is `0` should return `"1"`. I'm sure you could write that version of the function. Also note that the requirements seem to expect that the function `return`s a string rather than `print`ing things out.

Comment: Los of thanks, for yours suggestions. I will implement this function since I know now it an C(n, p) one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is some basic math :)

If you are using python >= 3.8:

```
from math import comb

def get_value_from_pyramid(n, r):
    return comb(n, r)
```

If you're using an older version of python:

```
import operator as op
from functools import reduce

def get_value_from_pyramid(n, r):
    r = min(r, n-r)
    numer = reduce(op.mul, range(n, n-r, -1), 1)
    denom = reduce(op.mul, range(1, r+1), 1)
    return numer // denom
```

More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941753/is-there-a-math-ncr-function-in-python)