# Numpy - vectorize the bivariate poisson pmf equation

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to write a function to evaluate the probability mass function for the bivariate poisson distribution.

[image]

This is easy when all of the parameters `(x, y, theta1, theta2, theta0)` are scalars, but tricky to scale up without loops to allow these parameters to be vectors. I need it to scale such that, for:

- `theta0` being a scalar - the "correlation parameter" in the equation
- `theta1` and `theta2` having length `l`
- `x`, `y` both having length `n`

the output array would have shape `(l, n, n)`.  For example, a slice `[j, :, :]` from the output array would look like:

[image]
The first part (the constant, before the summation) I think i've figured out:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import factorial

def constant(theta1, theta2, theta0, x, y):

    exponential_part = np.exp(-(theta1 + theta2 + theta0)).reshape(-1, 1, 1)
    x = np.tile(x, (len(x), 1)).transpose()
    y = np.tile(y, (len(y), 1))

    double_factorial = (np.power(np.array(theta1).reshape(-1, 1, 1), x)/factorial(x)) * \
                       (np.power(np.array(theta2).reshape(-1, 1, 1), y)/factorial(y))

    return exponential_part * double_factorial
```

But I'm struggling with the summation part. How can I vectorize a summation where the limits depend on variable arrays?

Comment: I don't think vectorizing the second part is feasible, as the summations are doing different amounts of work. You could of course compute all elements from the summation up to global max of x and y for each x/y/theta combination, and then sum up only to current min(x,y) per item, but that seems rather wasteful and probably not worthwile. Maybe rather look at memoization (functools.cache)? What is your `n`, anyway, and what would be common values of x and y?

Comment: `n` will usually be fairly small (like < 20) and x and y will usually be `= range(n). ` The problem is that this makes up one small component of a larger optimization problem, so needs to be efficient to run thousands or millions of times.

Comment: Are the xs and ys static over the optimization? In that case you could initialize a weight matrix of size [n, n, n] for (x, y, i) before processing, for the summarization term. Store `xCi * yCi * i!` in the matrix for each x/y/i combination, or zeros for where i > min(x,y). Then you only need to compute the theta^i term up for range(n) at each optimization step, and can multiply it against the static weight matrix.

Comment: Is `exponential_part` missing a call to `.reshape(-1, 1, 1)` ? I'm getting the same result for every value of theta, which I don't think is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have this figured out, based on the approach that @w-m suggests: calculate every possible summation term which could appear, based on the maximum x or y value which appears, and use a mask to get rid of the ones you don't want. Assuming you have your x and y terms go from 0 to N, in consecutive order, this is calculating up to three times more terms than are actually required, but this is offset by getting to use vectorization.

### Reference implementation

I wrote this by first writing a pure-Python reference implementation, which just implements your problem using loops. With 4 nested loops, it's not exactly fast, but it's handy to have while testing the numpy version.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import factorial, comb
import operator as op
from functools import reduce

def choose(n, r):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/4941932/530160
    r = min(r, n-r)
    numer = reduce(op.mul, range(n, n-r, -1), 1)
    denom = reduce(op.mul, range(1, r+1), 1)
    return numer // denom  # or / in Python 2

def reference_impl_constant(s_theta1, s_theta2, s_theta0, s_x, s_y):
    # Cast to float to prevent overflow
    s_theta1 = float(s_theta1)
    s_theta2 = float(s_theta2)
    s_theta0 = float(s_theta0)
    s_x = float(s_x)
    s_y = float(s_y)
    term1 = np.exp(-(s_theta1 + s_theta2 + s_theta0))
    term2 = (s_theta1 ** s_x / factorial(s_x))
    term3 = (s_theta2 ** s_y / factorial(s_y))
    assert term1 >= 0
    assert term2 >= 0
    assert term3 >= 0
    return term1 * term2 * term3

def reference_impl_constant_loop(theta1, theta2, theta0, x, y):
    theta_len = theta1.shape[0]
    xy_len = x.shape[0]
    constant_array = np.zeros((theta_len, xy_len, xy_len))
    for i in range(theta_len):
        for j in range(xy_len):
            for k in range(xy_len):
                s_theta1 = theta1[i]
                s_theta2 = theta2[i]
                s_theta0 = theta0
                s_x = x[j]
                s_y = y[k]
                constant_term = reference_impl_constant(s_theta1, s_theta2, s_theta0, s_x, s_y)
                assert constant_term >= 0
                constant_array[i, j, k] = constant_term
    return constant_array

def reference_impl_summation(s_theta1, s_theta2, s_theta0, s_x, s_y):
    sum_ = 0
    for i in range(min(s_x, s_y) + 1):
        sum_ += choose(s_x, i) * choose(s_y, i) * factorial(i) * ((s_theta0/s_theta1/s_theta2) ** i)
    assert sum_ >= 0
    return sum_

def reference_impl_summation_loop(theta1, theta2, theta0, x, y):
    theta_len = theta1.shape[0]
    xy_len = x.shape[0]
    summation_array = np.zeros((theta_len, xy_len, xy_len))
    for i in range(theta_len):
        for j in range(xy_len):
            for k in range(xy_len):
                s_theta1 = theta1[i]
                s_theta2 = theta2[i]
                s_theta0 = theta0
                s_x = x[j]
                s_y = y[k]
                summation_term = reference_impl_summation(s_theta1, s_theta2, s_theta0, s_x, s_y)
                assert summation_term >= 0
                summation_array[i, j, k] = summation_term
    return summation_array

def reference_impl(theta1, theta2, theta0, x, y):
    # all array inputs must be 1D
    assert len(theta1.shape) == 1
    assert len(theta2.shape) == 1
    assert len(x.shape) == 1
    assert len(y.shape) == 1
    # theta vectors must have same length
    theta_len = theta1.shape[0]
    assert theta2.shape[0] == theta_len
    # x and y must have same length
    xy_len = x.shape[0]
    assert y.shape[0] == xy_len
    # theta0 is scalar
    assert isinstance(theta0, (int, float))
    constant_array = np.zeros((theta_len, xy_len, xy_len))
    output = np.zeros((theta_len, xy_len, xy_len))
    constant_array = reference_impl_constant_loop(theta1, theta2, theta0, x, y)
    summation_array = reference_impl_summation_loop(theta1, theta2, theta0, x, y)
    output = constant_array * summation_array
    return output
```

### Numpy implementation

I split the implementation of this across two functions.

The fast_constant() function calculates everything to the left of the summation symbol. The fast_summation() function calculates everything inside the summation symbol.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import factorial, comb


def fast_summation(theta1, theta2, theta0, x, y):
    x = np.tile(x, (len(x), 1)).transpose()
    y = np.tile(y, (len(y), 1))
    sum_limit = np.minimum(x, y)
    max_sum_limit = np.max(sum_limit)
    i = np.arange(max_sum_limit + 1).reshape(-1, 1, 1)
    summation_mask = (i <= sum_limit)
    theta_ratio = (theta0 / (theta1 * theta2)).reshape(-1, 1, 1, 1)
    theta_to_power = np.power(theta_ratio, i)
    terms = comb(x, i) * comb(y, i) * factorial(i) * theta_to_power
    # mask out terms which aren't part of sum
    terms *= summation_mask
    # axis 0 is theta
    # axis 1 is i
    # axis 2 & 3 are x and y
    # so sum across axis 1
    terms = terms.sum(axis=1)
    
    return terms

def fast_constant(theta1, theta2, theta0, x, y):
    theta1 = theta1.astype('float64')
    theta2 = theta2.astype('float64')
    exponential_part = np.exp(-(theta1 + theta2 + theta0)).reshape(-1, 1, 1)
    # x and y must be 1D
    assert len(x.shape) == 1
    assert len(y.shape) == 1
    # x and y must have same shape
    assert x.shape == y.shape
    x_len, y_len = x.shape[0], y.shape[0]
    x = x.reshape((x_len, 1))
    y = y.reshape((1, y_len))

    double_factorial = (np.power(np.array(theta1).reshape(-1, 1, 1), x)/factorial(x)) * \
                       (np.power(np.array(theta2).reshape(-1, 1, 1), y)/factorial(y))

    return exponential_part * double_factorial

def fast_impl(theta1, theta2, theta0, x, y):
    return fast_summation(theta1, theta2, theta0, x, y) * fast_constant(theta1, theta2, theta0, x, y)
```

### Benchmarking

Assuming that X and Y range from 0 to 20, and that theta is centered somewhere inside that range, I get the result that the numpy version is roughly 280 times faster than the pure python reference.

### Numerical stability

I'm unsure how numerically stable this is. For example, when I center theta at 100, I get a floating-point overflow. Typically, when computing an expression which has lots of choose and factorial expressions inside it, you'll use some mathematical equivalent which results in smaller intermediate sums. In this case I have so little understanding of the math that I don't know how you'd do that.

Comment: I would have asked OP to provide a slow reference implementation next, but you just did that yourself, impressive work :). I wanted to try out your code, it's missing some imports for `reduce`, `op`, `comb`.