# How can I match up permutations of a long list with a shorter list (according to the length of the shorter list)?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, python-itertools, combinatorics

I’m having trouble wrapping my head around a algorithm I’m try to implement. I have two lists and want to take particular combinations from the two lists.

Here’s an example.

```
names = ['a', 'b']
numbers = [1, 2]
```

the output in this case would be:

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
[('b', 1), ('a', 2)]
```

I might have more names than numbers, i.e. `len(names) >= len(numbers)`. Here's an example with 3 names and 2 numbers:

```
names = ['a', 'b', 'c']
numbers = [1, 2]
```

output:

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
[('b', 1), ('a', 2)]
[('a', 1), ('c', 2)]
[('c', 1), ('a', 2)]
[('b', 1), ('c', 2)]
[('c', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html

Comment: @dm03514 I saw that, and found examples for somewhat similar goals using itertools but I'm prototyping in python but will write the final code in another language so I do not want to use any tools that are not avail elseway.

Comment: What you are asking for doesn't really make sense. If the first list contains A,B,C and the second contains 1,2, what result would you expect? It could be done if the example you gave had 4 different results of one letter and one number each (A1, A2, B1, B2), or if both lists had to have the same size.

Comment: I agree with interjay. Please specify the result in the non-equal size case, otherwise it's not possible to provide a general solution.

Comment: Hi Everyone, I updated the answer to show the output with 3 names and 2 numbers..I thought I explained it well, not sure why the downvote.

Comment: How would the output look like for `name = 'a', 'b', 'c'` and `number = 1, 2, 3`?

Comment: Is the order really important or is it enough to generate all of the "combinations" you want?
Also `A1 B2 == B2 A1`?

Comment: @Mr.Steak it would look like the example I had above with 2 names and 2 numbers but instead of 4 results there would be more because there are 3 items in the number list.   bakuriu The order does not really matter, trying to capture the combinations.

Comment: Note for future folks dup-ing questions to this one: There is a decent chance that [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/533905/364696) is a better duplicate target (lots of stuff that should use `product` is being duplicated here, even though this question is not properly solved that way). In rarer cases, [All possible replacements of two lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44593640/364696) may be better (when selecting a value from one of two lists at each index, which is a `product` solution again, with a `zip` prepass).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Just made the same mistake myself. I've now made an edit to remove fluff and misdirections from the question.

Comment: As far as I can tell, what OP was **actually** trying to do is generate permutations **of the names, whose length matches the length of the numbers**, and then combine each permutation's elements with the corresponding elements (i.e., `zip`ped together) from the numbers. That's a one-liner (`[list(zip(n, numbers)) for n in itertools.permutations(names, len(numbers))]`), but it's also clearly multiple separate steps (and a task that relatively few people would have).

Comment: The question demonstrably needs more focus (since solving it is a straightforward matter of applying those two steps) and demonstrably is unclear (since a bunch of the top answers interpreted something completely different). This is not at all a usable canonical.

Comment: At least the *accepted* answer got it right.

Comment: I went through and attempted to fix everything that was duped to here, and also dealt with some other questions that were linked to here.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

**Note**: This answer is for the specific question asked above. If you are here from Google and just looking for a way to get a Cartesian product in Python, `itertools.product` or a simple list comprehension may be what you are looking for - see the other answers.

---

Suppose `len(list1) >= len(list2)`. Then what you appear to want is to take all permutations of length `len(list2)` from `list1` and match them with items from list2. In python:

```
import itertools
list1=['a','b','c']
list2=[1,2]

[list(zip(x,list2)) for x in itertools.permutations(list1,len(list2))]
```

Returns

```
[[('a', 1), ('b', 2)], [('a', 1), ('c', 2)], [('b', 1), ('a', 2)], [('b', 1), ('c', 2)], [('c', 1), ('a', 2)], [('c', 1), ('b', 2)]]
```

Comment: The result is exactly what I want, but is it possible to share the logic behind how to do it?  If I convert my code to C or Java, I won't have access to zip or itertools(although they make life very very easy)

Comment: @user1735075 Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Comment: @user1735075: do you know that python is open source? So you may simply download the sources and see what do they do. 
+1 to Mr. Steak for pointing out that the documentation actually has a sample implementation that does not use `zip` and similar.

Comment: awesome..they document their algorithm. very helpful thank you interjay and mr. steak!

Comment: i literally cannot get this to work, even with your example... all i get is a list of zip object.. :|

Comment: @logic provides what should be the accepted solution.

Comment: can some one explain how can we calculate the total number of combinations? which is basically the length of the resulting array.

Comment: @m1nkeh in Python 3.x, [`zip` returns a special iterator rather than a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27431390). This answer was edited later to show the use of `list` to work around the issue.

Comment: @ArootinAghazaryan that is a completely separate question. Of course you can trivially ask for the `len` of that list like any other list, but counting permutations can be done much more directly and efficiently: see e.g. [counting combinations and permutations efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096573).

Answer (score 709):

The simplest way is to use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
a = ["foo", "melon"]
b = [True, False]
c = list(itertools.product(a, b))
>> [("foo", True), ("foo", False), ("melon", True), ("melon", False)]
```

Comment: OP wasn't asking for a Cartesian product, and this answer (as well as most of the others) doesn't give the expected result specified in the question.

Comment: @interjay you are very right but as too many people seem to find this answer as correct then I can only assume that the title of the question is lacking context.

Comment: @xpy The title is too short to explain everything. That's why you need to read the actual question.

Comment: OP wanted permuations, but Google sends anyone looking for combinations (like me) to this answer - glad to see it's got 8 times the votes!

Comment: @JoshFriedlander most of the people asking for any of these things don't understand the terminology; therefore, there are tons of questions that use the wrong terminology. Even if we close duplicates aggressively and make sure everything points at the correct duplicate for OP's problem, we then still end up with search misdirections.

Answer (score 231):

May be simpler than the simplest one above:

```
>>> a = ["foo", "bar"]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3]
>>> [(x,y) for x in a for y in b]  # for a list
[('foo', 1), ('foo', 2), ('foo', 3), ('bar', 1), ('bar', 2), ('bar', 3)]
>>> ((x,y) for x in a for y in b)  # for a generator if you worry about memory or time complexity.
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x1048de850>
```

without any import

Comment: Best solution! Thank you! Other solutions are either plain wrong or only work in specific cases like a > b etc.

Comment: Most Pythonic solution! (and avoids unnecessary imports)

Comment: Time complexity is O(n^2)

Comment: Bets solution!! Bare basics is the best way always

Comment: Sure, the time complexity is n^2, but surely this is completely unavoidable?

Answer (score 33):

I was looking for a list multiplied by itself with only unique combinations, which is provided as this function.

```
import itertools
itertools.combinations(list, n_times)
```

---

Here as an excerpt from [the Python docs on  `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) That might help you find what your looking for.

```
Combinatoric generators:

Iterator                                 | Results
-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------
product(p, q, ... [repeat=1])            | cartesian product, equivalent to a 
                                         |   nested for-loop
-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------
permutations(p[, r])                     | r-length tuples, all possible 
                                         |   orderings, no repeated elements
-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------
combinations(p, r)                       | r-length tuples, in sorted order, no 
                                         |   repeated elements
-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------
combinations_with_replacement(p, r)      | r-length tuples, in sorted order, 
                                         | with repeated elements
-----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------
product('ABCD', repeat=2)                | AA AB AC AD BA BB BC BD CA CB CC CD DA DB DC DD
permutations('ABCD', 2)                  | AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC
combinations('ABCD', 2)                  | AB AC AD BC BD CD
combinations_with_replacement('ABCD', 2) | AA AB AC AD BB BC BD CC CD DD
```

Answer (score 21):

the best way to find out all the combinations for large number of lists is:

```
import itertools
from pprint import pprint

inputdata = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d'],
    ['e', 'f'],
]
result = list(itertools.product(*inputdata))
pprint(result)
```

the result will be:

```
[('a', 'd', 'e'),
 ('a', 'd', 'f'),
 ('b', 'd', 'e'),
 ('b', 'd', 'f'),
 ('c', 'd', 'e'),
 ('c', 'd', 'f')]
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer!

Answer (score 15):

Or the KISS answer for short lists:

```
[(i, j) for i in list1 for j in list2]
```

Not as performant as itertools but you're using python so performance is already not your top concern...

I like all the other answers too!

Comment: Using `itertools` is not more complicated, and the performance difference is minor.

Answer (score 12):

You might want to try a one line list comprehension:

```
>>> [name+number for name in 'ab' for number in '12']
['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2']
>>> [name+number for name in 'abc' for number in '12']
['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2']
```

Answer (score 10):

a tiny improvement for the answer from interjay, to make the result as a flatten list.

```
>>> list3 = [zip(x,list2) for x in itertools.permutations(list1,len(list2))]
>>> import itertools
>>> chain = itertools.chain(*list3)
>>> list4 = list(chain)
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 1), ('c', 2), ('b', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 2), ('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

reference from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Answer (score 7):

Without `itertools` as a flattened list:

```
[(list1[i], list2[j]) for i in range(len(list1)) for j in range(len(list2))]
```

or in **Python 2**:

```
[(list1[i], list2[j]) for i in xrange(len(list1)) for j in xrange(len(list2))]
```

Answer (score 5):

Answering the question "given two lists, find all possible permutations of pairs of one item from each list" and using basic Python functionality (i.e., without itertools) and, hence, making it easy to replicate for other programming languages:

```
def rec(a, b, ll, size):
    ret = []
    for i,e in enumerate(a):
        for j,f in enumerate(b):
            l = [e+f]
            new_l = rec(a[i+1:], b[:j]+b[j+1:], ll, size)
            if not new_l:
                ret.append(l)
            for k in new_l:
                l_k = l + k
                ret.append(l_k)
                if len(l_k) == size:
                    ll.append(l_k)
    return ret

a = ['a','b','c']
b = ['1','2']
ll = []
rec(a,b,ll, min(len(a),len(b)))
print(ll)
```

Returns

```
[['a1', 'b2'], ['a1', 'c2'], ['a2', 'b1'], ['a2', 'c1'], ['b1', 'c2'], ['b2', 'c1']]
```

Answer (score 5):

The better answers to this only work for specific lengths of lists that are provided.

Here's a version that works for any lengths of input. It also makes the algorithm clear in terms of the mathematical concepts of combination and permutation.

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations
list1 = ['1', '2']
list2 = ['A', 'B', 'C']

num_elements = min(len(list1), len(list2))
list1_combs = list(combinations(list1, num_elements))
list2_perms = list(permutations(list2, num_elements))
result = [
  tuple(zip(perm, comb))
  for comb in list1_combs
  for perm in list2_perms
]

for idx, ((l11, l12), (l21, l22)) in enumerate(result):
  print(f'{idx}: {l11}{l12} {l21}{l22}')
```

This outputs:

```
0: A1 B2
1: A1 C2
2: B1 A2
3: B1 C2
4: C1 A2
5: C1 B2
```