# Make all possible n length permutations from n lists of integers (of possibly unequal length)

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

Example:

```
list1 = [0,1,2]
list2 = [0,1]
list3 = [0,1,2,3]
```

Then the permutations would be:

```
0,0,0
0,0,1
0,0,2
0,0,3
0,1,0
0,1,1
0,1,2
0,1,3
1,0,0
1,0,1
1,0,2
1,0,3
1,1,0
1,1,1
1,1,2
1,1,3
```

...and so on with 3 x 2 x 4  = 24 permutations.

The number of lists is not necessarily 3 (they can be any number, n) and the order matters so 0,0,1 is not the same as 0,1,0.

I understand I might have to use itertools somehow, but not sure how to approach this. I can't just make three nested loops since the number of lists varies.

This is a variation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935194/combinations-between-two-lists), but the number of lists varies and order matters.

I appreciate any help or hint. Thanks.

Comment: You didn't find a good duplicate because you're confusing "permutation" with "cartesian product"

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed a cartesian product and this is exactly what I wanted. I named it incorrectly as "permutation", my bad.

Comment: @user2898278 it's not "your bad" - don't worry about it. Sometimes just not knowing the name of something happens. You showed effort in research and showing input/output examples - it's a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list1 = [0,1,2]
list2 = [0,1]
list3 = [0,1,2,3]
listOfLists = [list1,list2,list3]
for list in itertools.product(*listOfLists):
    print(list)
```