# Combinations of two lists (not element-wise)

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
a = ['a', 'b']
b = [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to get the combinations produced between the elements of list `b` and the elements of list a but treating elements of `a` as pairs (or triples etc. etc.) as the example below which gives `len(b) ** len(a)` number of combinations.

```
c = ["a_1 b_1", "a_1 b_2", "a_1 b_3", "a_2 b_1", "a_2 b_2", "a_2 b_3", "a_3 b_1", "a_3 b_2" "a_3 b_3"]
```

I have tried to use `itertools.product` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935194/combinations-between-two-lists)) but this will give only the 6 possible combinations.

Comment: "I have tried to use itertools.product (as described here) but this will give only the 6 possible combinations. " That's because you tried to take the product of the A list with the B list. The actual problem is to take the product of the B list **with itself**, and then **use** the A list to **format** those results.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) but specify `repeat` to be `repeat=len(a)`. So you can use:

```
from itertools import product

def mul_product(a,b):
    for tup in product(b,repeat=len(a)):
        yield ' '.join('%s_%s'%t for t in zip(a,tup))
```

The `product(..)` will generate tuples like:

```
>>> list(product(b,repeat=len(a)))
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

So here the first element of the tuple is the one that is attached to `a_`, the second one to `b_`. Now we `zip(..)` them together with the `a` list, producing:

```
>>> list(map(lambda bi:list(zip(a,bi)),product(b,repeat=len(a))))
[[('a', 1), ('b', 1)], [('a', 1), ('b', 2)], [('a', 1), ('b', 3)], [('a', 2), ('b', 1)], [('a', 2), ('b', 2)], [('a', 2), ('b', 3)], [('a', 3), ('b', 1)], [('a', 3), ('b', 2)], [('a', 3), ('b', 3)]]
```

Now it is only a matter of formatting (`'%s_%s'%t`), and `' '.join(..)`ining them together and `yield` them (or you can use list comprehension to produce a list).

The result for your sample input is:

```
>>> list(mul_product(a,b))
['a_1 b_1', 'a_1 b_2', 'a_1 b_3', 'a_2 b_1', 'a_2 b_2', 'a_2 b_3', 'a_3 b_1', 'a_3 b_2', 'a_3 b_3']
```

Note that the elements here are generated lazily. This can be useful if you are for instance only interested in the first `k` ones, or when you do not want to generate all of them at once.

Answer (score 4):

You could explicitly create your pairwise items using `itertools.product`, then operate on those pairs again with `itertools.product`

```
import itertools
a = ['a', 'b']
b = [1, 2, 3]
pairs = [list(itertools.product([ai], b)) for ai in a]
```

`pairs` will contain the two lists that can fed into `itertools.product` again.

```
list(itertools.product(*pairs))
```

The result is:

```
[(('a', 1), ('b', 1)),
 (('a', 1), ('b', 2)),
 (('a', 1), ('b', 3)),
 (('a', 2), ('b', 1)),
 (('a', 2), ('b', 2)),
 (('a', 2), ('b', 3)),
 (('a', 3), ('b', 1)),
 (('a', 3), ('b', 2)),
 (('a', 3), ('b', 3))]
```

Comment: While you could indeed do this, the first step defeats the purpose of using `itertools.product`. It could just as easily be `pairs = [[(ai, bi) for bi in b] for ai in a]`. Yes, `itertools.product` would generate all of those 6 combinations, but without the required list structure; and once we have used a comprehension to get the required structure, `itertools.product` is no longer doing meaningful work.