# Multiply all combinations of two lists

Tags: python, list

I really want to know how to extract all the element from two lists and multiply each other. For example, if there are two lists

```
A=[1,3,5,7,9]
B=[2,4,6,8]
```

I want to do 1X2, 1X4, 1X6, 1x8, 3x2... etc.
One element from A X one element from B.
I tried to use zip but because of length difference, I couldn't get right answers.

Comment: You would want to do something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935194/combinations-between-two-lists

Comment: "I want to do 1X2, 1X4, 1X6, 1x8, 3x2... etc."  that is not random.  It looks like a Cartesian mesh of the two lists.   Is that what you want or do you actually want a **random** sample of the two lists?

Answer (score 10):

SInce your question seems to want the cartesian product between two lists, you can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to bind every element from `A` with every element from `B`:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> A = [1,3,5,7,9]
>>> B = [2,4,6,8]
>>> list(product(A, B))
[(1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 6), (1, 8), (3, 2), (3, 4), (3, 6), (3, 8), (5, 2), (5, 4), (5, 6), (5, 8), (7, 2), (7, 4), (7, 6), (7, 8), (9, 2), (9, 4), (9, 6), (9, 8)]
```

Then if you want to multiply the the two elements in each tuple, you can do this:

```
>>> [x * y for x, y in product(A, B)]
[2, 4, 6, 8, 6, 12, 18, 24, 10, 20, 30, 40, 14, 28, 42, 56, 18, 36, 54, 72]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a random value from a list, you can do something similar to the following:

```
import random
lst = [10,20,30]
x = random.choice(lst)
```

Importing the random library gives you access to a ton of random generation tools.  Per the random library documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html), *random.choice(seq)* returns a random element from a non-empty sequence, such as a list. Thus, the code above randomly selects an element from *lst* and assigns that value to the variable *x*.

I don't want to give the solution away until you've tried using the random library, so I'll let you figure out how to use the information above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loops:

Operation for each item in A with each item in B:

```
A=[1,3,5,7,9]
B=[2,4,6,8]

C = [] #Create an empty list
for i in A: #iter each element in A
    for j in B: #iter each element in B
        mult = i * j
        C.append(mult) #Append the result in the list C
print(C)
```

Operation with a random item in A with each item in B:

```
import numpy as np

A=[1,3,5,7,9]
B=[2,4,6,8]

C = [] #Create an empty list
for i in A: #iter each element in A
    i = np.random.randint(len(A)) #Chose a random number from A
    for j in B: #iter each element in B
        mult = A[i] * j #Multiply a random number from A with each element in B
        C.append(mult) #Append the result in the list C
print(C)
```