# How to generate an entire combination of two lists?

Tags: python

Suppose I have two lists.

```
noun=["Whispers", "Loners", "Gamblers"]
adj=["Shining", " Moaning"]
```

And I want to print:

```
The Shining Whispers
The Shining Loners
The Shining Gamblers
The Moaning Whispers
The Moaning Loners
The Moaning Gamblers
```

What should be my code to do this? These ones are small lists. I have bigger lists. So what code should I write to accomplish this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34032549/701049

Comment: this is not a duplicate of "combinations between two lists" just because there is an answer to that question that satisfies *this* one.

Comment: Lol! Than I'll create another question which asks to print it workout the "the" in front of the combination. hope it gets answers instead of being marked as duplicate 

Comment: I didn't understand the zip.[list] blah blah shit, so asked this.

Answer (score 2):

```
for a, b in itertools.product(noun, adj):
  print('The', a, b)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34032549/5476782