# Processing combinations but some elements cannot go together

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

Let's say I have the following elements: `['A', 'B', 1, 2]`

My idea is to get the following combinations:

- `('A', 1)`
- `('A', 2)`
- `('B', 1)`
- `('B', 2)`

But these are not **all** the combinations of the above sequence, e.g. I'm not considering (in purpose) `('A', 'B')` or `(1, 2)`

Using `itertools.combinations`, of course, gets me *all* the combinations:

```
from itertools import combinations

combinations(['A', 'B', 1, 2], 2)

# [('A', 'B'), ('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 1), ('B', 2), (1, 2)]
```

It's possible for me to internally group the elements that cannot go together:

```
elems = [('A', 'B'), (1, 2)]
```

However, `combinations` does not expect iterables inside other iterables, so the outcome is not really unexpected: `[(('A', 'B'), (1, 2))]`. Not what I want, nonetheless.

**What's the best way to achieve this?**

Comment: itertools.product should be the right answer (not the one accepted on the link I provided)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34032549/532312 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get the cartesian product of two lists:

```
from itertools import product

elems = [('A', 'B'), (1, 2)]

list(product(*elems))
# [('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 1), ('B', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.product` after forming new input with values grouped by type:

```
from itertools import product as prd, groupby as gb
d = ['A', 'B', 1, 2]
result = list(product(*[list(b) for _, b in gb(sorted(d, key=lambda x:str(type(x)), reverse=True), key=type)]))
```

Output:

```
[('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 1), ('B', 2)]
```

This solution will create new sublists grouped by data type, enabling robustness for future input and/or flexibility in element ordering in `d`:

```
d = ['A', 1, 'B', 2, (1, 2), 'C', 3, (3, 4), (4, 5)]
result = list(prd(*[list(b) for _, b in gb(sorted(d, key=lambda x:str(type(x)), reverse=True), key=type)]))
```

Output:

```
[((1, 2), 'A', 1), ((1, 2), 'A', 2), ((1, 2), 'A', 3), ((1, 2), 'B', 1), ((1, 2), 'B', 2), ((1, 2), 'B', 3), ((1, 2), 'C', 1), ((1, 2), 'C', 2), ((1, 2), 'C', 3), ((3, 4), 'A', 1), ((3, 4), 'A', 2), ((3, 4), 'A', 3), ((3, 4), 'B', 1), ((3, 4), 'B', 2), ((3, 4), 'B', 3), ((3, 4), 'C', 1), ((3, 4), 'C', 2), ((3, 4), 'C', 3), ((4, 5), 'A', 1), ((4, 5), 'A', 2), ((4, 5), 'A', 3), ((4, 5), 'B', 1), ((4, 5), 'B', 2), ((4, 5), 'B', 3), ((4, 5), 'C', 1), ((4, 5), 'C', 2), ((4, 5), 'C', 3)]
```