# Python: Rolling multi-sided dice

Tags: python, function, dice

I want to write a simple code:

We assume that a die can have an unlimited number of sides (natural number). There are two different dice available. The result is all possible combinations of the results of the rolls of two such dice.

Please help!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and consider reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You should try googling for the question answer first - mabye look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935194/combinations-between-two-lists, which is the first google results for "get all combinations of 2 lists python".  Also, I would recommend not trying to compute and return all combinations of lists/sets where the length could be infinity (from the unlimited sides).