# How to get combination from 2 list by taking 1 element from list1 and rest of the element from list2 and so on in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list1 = [1,1,2,4]
list2 = [2,3,5,6]
```

i would like get all combination like `[1,3,5,6], [1,3,5,6]` like all combination in python

My question is like list1=[1,2,3,4] list2=[5,6,7,8] I need to see the lists like [1,5,6,7] [5,2,7,8] meaning all possible combination of 2 list.please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [combinations between two lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935194/combinations-between-two-lists)

Comment: I have tried below                                                                                                         x = [1, 2, 3,9]
y = [4, 5,8,7]
new_array = np.array(np.meshgrid(x, y)).T.reshape(-1,4)                                            The Result is Combine array:
[[1 4 1 5]
 [1 8 1 7]
 [2 4 2 5]
 [2 8 2 7]
 [3 4 3 5]
 [3 8 3 7]
 [9 4 9 5]
 [9 8 9 7]]                   But my Requirement is like [1,5,8,7][4,2,8,7] like on

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the Cartesian product of multiple lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/how-to-get-the-cartesian-product-of-multiple-lists)

Answer (score 1):

Like this IIUC:

```
>>> print([[i] + list2[1:] for i in list1])
[[1, 3, 5, 6], [1, 3, 5, 6], [2, 3, 5, 6], [4, 3, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: My question is like list1=[1,2,3,4] list2=[5,6,7,8]                   I need to see the lists like [1,5,6,7]   [5,2,7,8] meaning all possible combination of 2 list.please help.

Comment: It is not quite clear to me what is expected. Please adjust your question, explain the steps from input to result and give full output examples. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example on how to best do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```py
import itertools
list1 = [1,1,2,4]
list2 = [2,3,5,6]
combination_list = list(itertools.combinations(list1 + list2, 4))
```

this joins the two lists into one list (i.e, [1,1,2,4,2,3,5,6]) and takes all the 4 element combinations.