# number of path grid problem Python, Memory Error and Recursion Error:

Tags: python, dynamic, grid, dynamic-programming

so i tried to solve a simple grid problem and i solve like this :\

```
def grid_count (n,m):
    if m == 1 and n == 1:
        return 1
    if m == 0 or n == 0:
        return 0
    return grid_count(m-1,n) + grid_count(m,n-1)
```

and here N X M is rows and column of a grid but is not good for big input
for eg. if i input--- > 18X18 for N and M
it will give me a runtime error so i used
dynamic approach
and

```
dic ={}
def grid_count (n,m):
    # key  = str(n)+","+str(m)
    key = n*m
    if key in dic:
        return dic[key]
    if m == 1 and n == 1:
        dic[key] = 1
    if m == 0 or n == 0:
        dic[key] = 0
    dic[key] = grid_count(m-1,n) + grid_count(m,n-1)
    return dic[key]
```

if i do this i have 2 type of error

**error_1**
1 : RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object

and i got the answer for this
i.e. --- >

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(100**8)
```

but after that one more error is rising

**error_2**
2 : MemoryError: Stack overflow
i dont know what i do know ,

any help!!

Comment: It seems like a factorial result. i.e. it'll get large and blow out the stack depth and memory quickly - you should have this issue with this problem. Have a look at answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935194/permutations-between-two-lists-of-unequal-length) question.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as a duplicate. The question in this post *can* be solved using the answers in the linked post but doesn't have to be, as demonstrated in the accepted answer here. Furthermore the questions themselves are not in any way duplicates of each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reach your base case you should just return the value instead of storing it in `dic`.:

```
    if m == 1 and n == 1:
        return 1
    if m == 0 or n == 0:
        return 0
```

Alternatively, you can initialize `dic` with your known values:

```
dic = {0: 0, 1: 1}
def grid_count (n,m):
    key = n*m
    if key in dic:
        return dic[key]
    dic[key] = grid_count(m-1,n) + grid_count(m,n-1)
    return dic[key]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a combination issue. You can calculate the answer instead of walking the whole (very large) tree.

```
from math import factorial

def grid_count(n,m):
    if m == 1 and n == 1:
        return 1
    if m == 0 or n == 0:
        return 0
    return grid_count(m-1,n) + grid_count(m,n-1)

def grid_calc(n,m):
    m -= 1
    num = factorial(m + n - 1)
    den = factorial(m) * factorial(n - 1)
    return num//den

for c in [grid_count, grid_calc]:
    print(c(12,12))
```

Timing is

```
%%timeit
grid_count(12,12)
# 364 ms ± 1.77 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
grid_calc(12,12)
# 503 ns ± 3.88 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```