# How to make couple for elements from two list (different size) in Python?

Tags: python, list

I need to make couple for elements from two lists (two lists are different size)
Ex:

```
x = ([3,2], [4,6,-8])
y = ([-5,1,4], [13,9], [7,5,-1,10])
```

Result:

```
new_list = ([3, -5], [3, 1], [3, 4], [3, 13], [3, 9], [3, 7], [3, 5], [3, -1],[3, 10], [2, -5], [2, 1] ......<sorry, there're too many>.... [-8, 5], [-8, -1], [-8, 10])
```

Thanks for support!

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In two steps, 1) flatten your list of lists, 2) `itertools.product`

Flatten your list of lists:
[How to make a flat list out of a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists)

```
flat_list = itertools.chain(*iterable_of_lists)
```

Use itertools to create the product of the two lists.

```
itertools.product(x, y)
```

Example from OP:

```
import itertools

x = ([3,2], [4,6,-8])
y = ([-5,1,4], [13,9], [7,5,-1,10])
x_flat = itertools.chain(*x)
y_flat = itertools.chain(*y)
list(itertools.product(x_flat, y_flat))
```

result:

```
[(3, -5), (3, 1), (3, 4), (3, 13), (3, 9), (3, 7), (3, 5), (3, -1), (3, 10), (2, -5), (2, 1), (2, 4), (2, 13), (2, 9), (2, 7), (2, 5), (2, -1), (2, 10), (4, -5), (4, 1), (4, 4), (4, 13), (4, 9), (4, 7), (4, 5), (4, -1), (4, 10), (6, -5), (6, 1), (6, 4), (6, 13), (6, 9), (6, 7), (6, 5), (6, -1), (6, 10), (-8, -5), (-8, 1), (-8, 4), (-8, 13), (-8, 9), (-8, 7), (-8, 5), (-8, -1), (-8, 10)]
```

Comment: If you are going to import `itertools` anyways, you could just use https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable

Comment: I agree, `chain` is better. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `x`, `y` and `new_list` in the examples are actually tuples and not lists, because you use `()` instead of `[]`.

Based on your expected result, I assume that you don't really need lists of lists here, you just take flat lists:

```py
x = [3,2,4,6,-8]
y = [-5,1,4,13,9,7,5,-1,10]
```

And find each combination between `x` and `y`. Which can be done using `itertools.product`

Answer (score 0):

Using [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product, chain

new_list = list(product(chain(*x), chain(*y)))
```

```
[(3, -5), (3, 1), (3, 4), (3, 13), (3, 9), (3, 7), (3, 5), (3, -1), (3, 10), (2, -5), (2, 1), (2, 4), (2, 13), (2, 9), (2, 7), (2, 5), (2, -1), (2, 10), (4, -5), (4, 1), (4, 4), (4, 13), (4, 9), (4, 7), (4, 5), (4, -1), (4, 10), (6, -5), (6, 1), (6, 4), (6, 13), (6, 9), (6, 7), (6, 5), (6, -1), (6, 10), (-8, -5), (-8, 1), (-8, 4), (-8, 13), (-8, 9), (-8, 7), (-8, 5), (-8, -1), (-8, 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have two tuples containing lists, not lists of numbers and the expected result is a tuple containing two-length lists. So, you have to convert those tuples of lists to simple tuples first, following this solution (with a little change): https://stackoverflow.com/a/952952/11882999

```
x = ([3,2], [4,6,-8])
y = ([-5,1,4], [13,9], [7,5,-1,10])
x_tuple = tuple(item for sublist in x for item in sublist)
y_tuple = tuple(item for sublist in y for item in sublist)
```

Then following this solution (with a little change), you can calculate the combinations of two tuples easily: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39064769/11882999

```
result = tuple([x, y] for x in x_tuple for y in y_tuple)

>> ([3, -5], [3, 1], [3, 4], ..., [-8, 5], [-8, -1], [-8, 10])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).