# Python generate sets of pairings between two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-itertools

Given two lists in Python

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
```

We can use `c=list(itertools.product(a,b))` to generate all possible permutations, this will output

```
[(1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Now we need to generate these sets from `c`

```
[[(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)],
 [(1,4),(2,6),(3,5)],
 [(1,5),(2,4),(3,6)],
 [(1,5),(2,6),(3,4)],
 [(1,6),(2,4),(3,5)],
 [(1,6),(2,5),(3,4)]]
```

Each list here is a possible pairing of all elements in `a` with `b`. The number of pairings is the number of possible permutations taking two at a time. The solution needs work for any number of elements in `a` and `b`.

Comment: `[list(zip(x,b)) for x in itertools.permutations(a,len(b))]` - this does as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/12935562/3169868, thanks!

Comment: What you are actually trying to do is get the permutations of `b`, and then use `a` to "label" them (or perhaps vice-versa).