# Python get all sets of N pairs from two lists

Tags: python, python-itertools

This is some kind of elementary task in itertools probably, but my brain is not working today and I can't seem to find it answered here already.

Suppose I have two lists with different numbers of elements. Their indices are

```
i1 = list(range(N))
i2 = list(range(M))
```

for say `N=3`, `M=4` we have

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

I now want to construct all possible sets of pairs of length K from these two lists. So for example for K=1 we have

```
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(2, 0)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
(2, 3)
```

and for K=2 we have

```
(0,0), (1,1)
(0,0), (1,2)
(0,0), (1,3)
(0,0), (2,1)
(0,0), (2,2)
(0,0), (2,3)
(0,1), (1,0)
(0,1), (1,2)
(0,1), (1,3)
(0,2), (1,0)
(0,2), (1,1)
(0,2), (1,3)
...
<and so it goes on...>
```

i.e. we are drawing one value from each list to make a pair, without replacement, and doing this K times to make K pairs. And we want to obtain all possible sets of such pairs.

For K=1 I guess this is the cartesian product of the lists, but it's more complicated for K=2 and above.

Note that the elements in each pair in each set are drawn from the lists without replacement. So each item from each list can appear in at most one pair in each set of pairs.

Edit: The answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12935562/1447953 solves the problem when K=min(N,M), i.e. when finding the longest possible sets of pairs, but it doesn't work for smaller K .

For additional context: I am working on a spectral peak matching problem. I have two line spectra, which have varying numbers of peaks in them, and I am working on an algorithm to determine whether any of the peaks line up with each other. This involves comparing peaks from one spectrum against those in the other spectrum, so I need to iterate over all the ways the peaks might possibly be paired up for comparison (for differing numbers of potential simultaneous matches).

Comment: @blhsing arguably unclear question (seems like OP has unspecified constraints on the "sets"), but probably not an exact duplicate...

Comment: you should explain why e.g. `(0,0), (0.1)` is not in your list, also could be clearer if you gave expected output (and rationale) with e.g. `i2 = list('abcd')`

Comment: @Julien Indeed. I've reopened the question for you guys to vote to close the question again for being unclear then.

Comment: @Julien edited to clarify that the pairs are drawn without replacement from the input lists.

Comment: Combinations from the product?

Comment: You're expected to show us the code you've written that doesn't work. This also smells like a homework question. Nothing wrong with asking for help with your homework but in that case it is even more important that you show us your attempted solution and you should be honest about your reason for asking for help.

Comment: @Andreas Deak - what should work is first doing K=1, i.e. the Cartesian product, then for each element of that delete that pair from the original lists and compute the Cartesian product of the remainder to get all the next possible pairs. And iterate for higher K. But I think there are probably duplicates to be deleted doing it this way, so probably there is a cleaner and more efficient method.

Comment: @KurtisRader it's not homework, it came up in a spectral peak matching problem I'm working on. As for not working code, ok sure there was another question that solved the problem for the maximal sets of pairs but not lesser K, will try to find it again...

Comment: @BenFarmer, What does "it's just a" mean? Again, show us your attempted solution and provide some context.

Comment: @Kurtis Rader - not sure what you are talking about, but as stated above will find again the previous partial solution I had.

Comment: @KurtisRader - I have added a link to another answer that solves the problem in a special case, which is the best I found so far.

Comment: When I posted my comment your most recent comment, in its totality, was "it's just a". Perhaps just a quirk of S.O.'s commenting system but I suspect you inadvertently posted your comment before you were done revising it as I now see, in its place, a comment that makes more sense. Still, I don't understand why you didn't include your attempted solution in the original problem statement nor why you need to "try to find it again". Surely, you still have the file containing your code on your computer?

Comment: @KurtisRader yes but I'm on mobile now and won't be back at my computer until tomorrow. Nevertheless the code I have is the same as in the answer I have now linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically a product of k-permutations of the two lists:

```
from itertools import product, permutations

def f(i1, i2, k):
    for p in product(permutations(i1, k), permutations(i2, k)):
        yield tuple(zip(*p))
```

so that:

```
i1 = list(range(3))
i2 = list(range(4))

print(*f(i1, i2, 1), sep='\n')
print(*f(i1, i2, 2), sep='\n')
```

outputs:

```
((0, 0),)
((0, 1),)
((0, 2),)
((0, 3),)
((1, 0),)
((1, 1),)
((1, 2),)
((1, 3),)
((2, 0),)
((2, 1),)
((2, 2),)
((2, 3),)
((0, 0), (1, 1))
((0, 0), (1, 2))
((0, 0), (1, 3))
((0, 1), (1, 0))
((0, 1), (1, 2))
((0, 1), (1, 3))
((0, 2), (1, 0))
((0, 2), (1, 1))
((0, 2), (1, 3))
((0, 3), (1, 0))
((0, 3), (1, 1))
((0, 3), (1, 2))
((0, 0), (2, 1))
((0, 0), (2, 2))
((0, 0), (2, 3))
((0, 1), (2, 0))
((0, 1), (2, 2))
((0, 1), (2, 3))
((0, 2), (2, 0))
((0, 2), (2, 1))
((0, 2), (2, 3))
((0, 3), (2, 0))
((0, 3), (2, 1))
((0, 3), (2, 2))
((1, 0), (0, 1))
((1, 0), (0, 2))
((1, 0), (0, 3))
((1, 1), (0, 0))
((1, 1), (0, 2))
((1, 1), (0, 3))
((1, 2), (0, 0))
((1, 2), (0, 1))
((1, 2), (0, 3))
((1, 3), (0, 0))
((1, 3), (0, 1))
((1, 3), (0, 2))
((1, 0), (2, 1))
((1, 0), (2, 2))
((1, 0), (2, 3))
((1, 1), (2, 0))
((1, 1), (2, 2))
((1, 1), (2, 3))
((1, 2), (2, 0))
((1, 2), (2, 1))
((1, 2), (2, 3))
((1, 3), (2, 0))
((1, 3), (2, 1))
((1, 3), (2, 2))
((2, 0), (0, 1))
((2, 0), (0, 2))
((2, 0), (0, 3))
((2, 1), (0, 0))
((2, 1), (0, 2))
((2, 1), (0, 3))
((2, 2), (0, 0))
((2, 2), (0, 1))
((2, 2), (0, 3))
((2, 3), (0, 0))
((2, 3), (0, 1))
((2, 3), (0, 2))
((2, 0), (1, 1))
((2, 0), (1, 2))
((2, 0), (1, 3))
((2, 1), (1, 0))
((2, 1), (1, 2))
((2, 1), (1, 3))
((2, 2), (1, 0))
((2, 2), (1, 1))
((2, 2), (1, 3))
((2, 3), (1, 0))
((2, 3), (1, 1))
((2, 3), (1, 2))
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/WVkVKW

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to get it without duplicates off the bat? I.e. I don't care about the ordering in the sets of pairs, so {(0,0), (1,1)} and {(1,1), (0,0)} are the same to me. I can of course just put them in sets to delete duplicates though.

Comment: use a set + sorting to remove "duplicates": `{tuple(sorted(zip(*p))) for p in product(permutations(i1, k), permutations(i2, k))}`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to @blhsing's solution, you can build it up manually recursively.
Only posting for educational purpose, other answer is better.

```
def pair_sets(i1, i2, sets, s, K):
    if len(s) == K:
        sets.append(s) # add current set to list of sets
    if not i1 or not i2:
        return 
    for i,x in enumerate(i1):
        for j,y in enumerate(i2[:]):
            s_ = s.copy()
            s_.append((x,y)) # add pair to current set
            pair_sets(i1[i+1:], i2[:j]+i2[j+1:], sets, s_, K) # keep building up current set
    return sets

pair_sets(i1, i2, [], [], 2)
```