# Python - Generating/iterating a combination

Tags: python, combinations

I'd like to start by saying that I'm fairly new to Python and am very interested in coding in general. I have some familiarity with basic concepts, but the functions used specifically in Python are largely unknown to me. Fwiw I'm a visual/experiential learner.

I'd also like to state right off the bat that I apologize if this question has been asked and already answered. I found alot of "similar" questions, but none that really helped me find a solution.

## Problem

As stated in my topic title I'm interested in creating an "output" (correct terminology?) of an nCr into a list or whatever is the best method to view it.

It would be a 10 choose 5. The ten variables could be numbers, letters, names, words, etc. There are no repeats and no order to the combinations.

### Research

I would like to say that I'd looked at similar topics like this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096573/counting-combinations-and-permutations-efficiently) and found the concepts helpful, but have discovered that in the example code:

```
    from itertools import izip

    reduce(lambda x, y: x * y[0] / y[1], izip(xrange(n - r + 1, n+1), xrange(1, r+1)), 1)
```

The reduce tool/function isn't used that way anymore. I think I read that it changed to *functools* as of Python 3.

### Question

How would the above code (examples are helpful) or any other be updated/changed to accommodate for reduce? Are there any other ways to output the combination results?

`***Edit***`
I think I didn't clearly connect the content of the **Problem** and **Question** headings. Basically my main question is under the **Problem** heading. While it is helpful to see how a person can use the *itertools* to make combinations from a list, I don't have any idea how to output the 10 choose 5. :\

Comment: `reduce` used to be a built-in function. It's now a function inside the `functools` package. Nothing else should have changed. The equivalent line in Python3 is `reduce(lambda x, y: x * y[0] / y[1], zip(range(n - r + 1, n+1), range(1, r+1)), 1)` after the import `from functools import reduce`. Note the changes `izip -> zip` and `xrange -> range`

Comment: Could you give an example of what you would like the output to look like?

Comment: I'm looking for something like: `Variables are 1/a/2/b/3/c/4/d/5/e output is 1a2b3, 1a2bc, 1a2b4...` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for combination in itertools.combinations('ABCDEFGHIJ', 5):
>>>    print(''.join(combination))
ABCDE
ABCDF
ABCDG
ABCDH
ABCDI
ABCDJ
ABCEF
ABCEG
ABCEH
ABCEI
```

If so, it's done. If you want to learn how to implement the `combinations` function yourself, you're lucky because the [itertools.combinations documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) gives an implementation.